# Adding a folder to a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, raylib

[image]

I added a folder called "MySamples" the the Examples project. However when I try and use the folder it says its not recognized. Ive tried cleaning/rebuiling the solution. I tried restarting VSstudio and reven restarting PC. How can I get Program.cs to recognize and use the "MySamples" folder.

Comment: You should include the image information below with your question. As Miguel said, the namespace has to be consistent with what you are referencing, that's why the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any file inside the folder MySamples that defines a class under the namespace "Examples.MySamples"? It looks like there's no such namespace defined, and that's why you are not able to reference it.

Comment: yes there is a file like this https://imgur.com/a/HdDIJgc

Comment: You can reference namespaces, not folders. As I see on the picture you've attached, the namespace in which `easings_testbed2` class is defined is "Examples". Change the namespace to "Examples.MySamples" and it should work.

Comment: @Ghoyos You should read the question guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it specifically warns against using screenshots of code where not necessary.